# How to read environmentVariables in msbuild ? asp.net core c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, msbuild

I need to read environment variable in build defined in launchsettings.json file. I have tried many ways but none of them worked.

1)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <UsingTask TaskName="test" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("{customvariable}"));]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
</Project>
```

2) I tried using ITask in Microsoft.Build.Framework

3) Tried property function

```
System.Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable
```

Nothing worked.
There is some issue with the same in git 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/3260

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think all the Environment Variables are loaded as `msbuild` variables, so, according to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build):

> All environment variables are available to the Microsoft Build Engine (MSBuild) project file as properties.

So you can access them like other variables defined in the `msbuild` file.

Comment: I tried but didn't work. You can find on the link same given by you has an open issue. So, I am looking for a workaround.